# Undefined variable mysqli php

Tags: mysqli

hola tengo el siguiente problema con esto hay algo mal:

```
    $results = $mysqli->query ( " SELECT * fron jose");
    print '<table border="1">';

    while ($row=$results->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      print '<tr>';
      print '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
      print '<td>'.$row['User'].'</td>';
      print '<tr>';# code...
    }
      print '</table>';
```

[image: una imagen del problema]

Comment: En tu código no esta definida la variable $conn y ese es el primer error que te muestra.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\jose.php on line 80

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\jose.php:80 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\jose.php on line 80

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tienes error de sintaxis en la consulta, es `from`, no `fron`. Corrige: **`SELECT * from jose`**

Comment: gracias ya corre ji pero dice los mismo :(

Comment: Edita la pregunta poniendo lo que dice el mensaje de error. Ponlo en texto, no en imagen. Y define cómo se llama tu variable de conexión, por lo que se ve en la imagen y por comentarios anteriores, ya van por lo menos tres nombres distintos. En tu código se llama `$mysqli`, debe llamarse así también donde te conectas, de lo contrario no funcionará.

Comment: XD tenia un cierre de conexión antes del select